# Does the phoenix frameworks phoenix.js websocket client have anything specific to the framework?

Tags: websocket, phoenix-framework

Can I use the phoenix.js file in another project that has a websocket server or is there code that is specific to phoenix in there?

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/assets/js/phoenix.js

I am looking at the javascript code and I am not seeing anything specific to the phoenix framework.

Hoping someone with more experience could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

That code does not seem to be very Phoenix specific indeed, but you still have to have server code to support all/most of the functionality in the `Socket` class, like: channels, topics, LongPoll transport, a heartbeat, Presence information.

I don't know how standardised these concepts and implementations are in comparison to other websocket servers.